# Indexing error when running this binary search method in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
    def unique(ip):
         file = open("/home/USER/Desktop/ipAddreses.txt",'r')
         list = file.readlines()
         list.sort()
         low = 1
         hi = len(list)
         target = convertToStr(ip)
         if hi > 1:
                 while low <= hi:
                 mid = low + (hi-low)/2
                 if list[mid] == target:
                     file.close()
                     return False            
                 elif list[mid] < target: 
                     low = mid+1
                 else:
                     hi = mid-1
         else:
                 if target == list[0]:
                     return False

file.close()
return True
```

Get this error:

```
    if list[mid] == target:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Purpose is to  search through generated ip addresses to make sure all randomly created ip addresses are unique. was working before ... got home and now i get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't immediately see how to fix the problem with your code, but if you just want to solve the problem at hand, this probably isn't the best way to do it.

- Sorting and then doing binary search is almost always worse than just doing a straightforward linear search over an array, in general. Sorting is O(n log n) and in practice requires "looking at" each element of the array at least once, and requires storing at least one copy of the entire file in memory. If you just iterate over the file, you look at each element at most once, and only use a constant amount of memory.
- You probably shouldn't be implementing binary search yourself anyway (unless you're doing it for practice), because as you've discovered it's easy to get the fiddly bits wrong; use [the `bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) instead.
- It looks like there's an exit path from your code where you don't explicitly close `file` (the `target == list[0]` part). This is why `with` statements are nice; they handle that for you.

You could do it like this instead:

```
def unique(ip):
    ip_str = convertToStr(ip)
    with open("/home/USER/Desktop/ipAddreses.txt", 'r') as f:
         return all(line.rstrip() != ip_str for line in f)
```

If you're going to call `unique` on a bunch of ip addresses, you could avoid reading the whole file each time, and get much faster lookups, using a `set`:

```
with open("/home/USER/Desktop/ipAddreses.txt", 'r') as f:
    ip_addresses = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)

def unique(ip):
    return convertToStr(ip) not in ip_addresses
```

---

That said, comparing to [the source of the `bisect` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py#l67), it seems that the differences are that you use `while low <= hi` but they use `while lo < hi`, and you use `hi = mid - 1` where they use `hi = mid`. I think (though I haven't run it to make sure) that if the string you're searching for would be the largest one in the list, you end up with `low == hi == len(list)`, so then you set `mid = len(list)`, which breaks when you do `list[mid]`.

Comment: Dougal THANK YOU!!!!!!!! the ultimate goal of this is to improve my understanding while finishing my assignment for class.... but  may I ask as to why I shouldn't be implementing binary search myself? Better yet, where should one always implement a binary search?

Comment: Of course it's worthwhile to implement binary search yourself to make sure you understand the algorithm. But once you've done that, if you're just trying to _use_ binary search, it's not worth rewriting the code, since it takes a fair bit of space and effort and is mildly annoying to get right. Calling the standard library's implementation makes it easier to read, easier to write, easier to get right (fewer places to make a mistake), and also runs faster (since it's implemented in C).

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind, I am also creating random addresses to the same file,  will using the:

        with open(..)

autoupdate for the newly created ip addresses

Comment: If you're talking about the approach that makes a `set` - no, it won't but you can add them directly to the set with `ip_addresses.add(new_ip_str)` as well as adding them to the file.

Comment: THank you again! you have been a big help!

Answer (score -1):

Check mid for is it exists in list.

```
if mid in list:
    if list[mid] == target:
        # ...
```

Comment: `mid` is an integer. It's not going to be in a list of strings.

Comment: I have tried that edit of code still now i receive that error at the elif statement. I am utterly confused. I understand the logic of the binary search but I have no idea as to why mid is going out of index. I had a very large  txt file when i made the switch to binary search instead of brute forcing the search. I a wondering if it has to be large set of data for it to work